# Изменение свойств слоя при наведении на него курсора

Tags: html, css

Допустим, имеется пример:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Пример</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #separator {
        border-radius: 8px;
        color: #ccc; /* Цвет текста */
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15); /* Цвет фона */
        margin: 5px; /* Отступы вокруг текста */
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px; /* Отступы вокруг текста */
        width: 100px;
    }

    a:hover { 
        display: block; /* Ссылка как блочный элемент */
        color: white; /* Цвет ссылок при наведении на них курсора мыши */ 
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="separator"><a href="popular.html">ссылка</a></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

как сделать так, чтобы весь слой (а не его часть) менял цвет при наведении на него курсора?

Answer (score 1):

Без JS вариант 1 - прописывать одинаковые стили псевдокласса **hover** и для родительского и для дочернего елемента, т.е.

```
a:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#separator:hover {
    backgound:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
/*т.к. ссылка находится в это еллементе - сработают обоа правила*/
}
```

Естественно недостатки очевидны - даже если пользователь просто наведете на блок separator - сработает hover... Сделаем же так чтобы все работало так как надо, но без js тут нам уже не обойтись...
Конкретно в вашем примере можно сделать прмиерно так:

```
<div id="separator"><a href="popular.html"
    onmouseover="this.parentNode.style.background = ''"
    onmouseout ="this.parentNode.style.background = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'"
>ссылка</a></div>
```

Comment: Пора самому учить яву =)

>если пользователь просто наведете на блок separator - сработает hover...

именно это мне и нужно было, нечто вроде кнопки чтобы получилось...
одно "но" - когда наводим на блок курсор - его цвет меняется, однако, цвет ссылки изменится только если навести курсор прямо на нее, можно ли заставить ее менять цвет при наведении курсора на блок?

PS: я имею ввиду не прибегая к средствам явы?

Comment: нет, нельзя

Comment: Нет, можно)

    #separator:hover a{color:red}

Comment: или я неправильно понял вопрос или нельзя

Answer (score 1):

Ява, ява и еще раз ява :)

```
<div id="separator" onmouseover="document.getElementById('link').style.color = ''" onmouseout ="document.getElementById('link').style.color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'"><a href="popular.html" id="link">ссылка</a></div>
```

В данном примере при наведении на блок должен меняться цвет ссылки